# Export from Excel and import to Word row by row asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, import, export

I created a project that export an excel file to gridView and import it to word. Right now I achieved this with clicking every row's id which is sent to ExportData() method.

Now what I want to achieve is, with clicking a button called ImportALL, creating seperated word documents for each row in the gridView.

For example for every row in gridview, I want to have something like

doc1.docx (including gridview's first row data)

doc2.docx (including gridview's second row data)

doc3.docx (including gridview's third row data)

For example:

Here is my model.cs

```
 public class Doc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string PriceWord { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my reading exporting excel data contoller

```
if (excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + excelFile.FileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                }
                excelFile.SaveAs(path);
                ExcelDoc.Application application = new ExcelDoc.Application();
                ExcelDoc.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
                ExcelDoc.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                ExcelDoc.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                List<Doc> docs = new List<Doc>();
                for (int row = 2; row < range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    Doc d = new Doc();
                    d.Id = Int32.Parse(((ExcelDoc.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text);
                    d.Name = ((ExcelDoc.Range)range.Cells[row, 2]).Text;
                    d.Price = Decimal.Parse((((ExcelDoc.Range)range.Cells[row, 3]).Text));
                    d.PriceWord = numberToWordConverter(s.Price.ToString());
                    d.Quantity = ((ExcelDoc.Range)range.Cells[row, 4]).Text;
                    docs.Add(d);
                }

                ViewBag.Docs = docs;
                TempData["docs"] = docs;
                return View("Success");

            }

            else
            {

                ViewBag.Error = "File type is incorrect";
                return View("Index");
            }
```

And here is the word exporting method.

```
      public ActionResult ExportData(int? id)
    {
        var docs = TempData["Docs"] as List<Doc>;
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = docs.Where(x=> x.Id == id);
        gv.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=dosya.doc");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
            Response.Charset = string.Empty;

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Also, I have a problem with below part. Unless I stopped the execution of Excel file in task manager, I have an error like " cannot be accessed because it is used by another process"

```
   if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

file read-write operations are not allowed to be used by another process if you do not close at the end of the operation.

```
    workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    application.Quit();
    ViewBag.Docs = docs;
    TempData["docs"] = docs;
    return View("Success");
```

replace your code

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.doc", "WordFileName"));
Response.Charset = "";
System.IO.StringWriter stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
gv.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
Response.Write(stringwriter.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, it works. Do you have an idea about the first question above(exporting row by row) ?

Comment: @Finagle do you want each line in a different file? or all rows one file? or all the data in one file?

Comment: Each line in different file.